# Azure VM Windows Data Disk - How do I know if it's HDD or SSD?

Tags: windows, azure, ssd

I'm on a Windows VM, and, for example, have 3 data disks attached, each 100GB.

I know 2 of them are HDD and one SSD.

Is there any more-or-less easy way of identifying which disk is SSD and which is HDD from within the VM?

Answer (score 3):

The Azure portal will show the disk type (SSD or HDD). Select your VM, and on the Settings section, go to Disks. There you should see the disks attached to the VM.[image]

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but I wanted to know this from within VM. E.g. you are RDPing to VM and you have drives E, F, G - each 100GB. How would I know which one is SDD and which one HDD? Hope that clarifies what I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: Type show "Page blob" after new changes in azure what this means now?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to find this out for a VM is to find the `Size` on the `Overview` page, then look it up on the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cloud-services/).

[image: size on overview page]

Answer (score 0):

You should always check from azure portal. There are many optimizations done on VM's and chances are high that most of the SSD detecting softwares will not be able to detect it.